# Flag subset of a dataframe based on another dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've encountered a problem which I didn't succeed to solve, for now.
Your assistance on this one would be highly appreciated.

I have 2 dataframes:

```
first_df:
   A  B  C  D
1  1  a  q  zz
2  2  b  w  xx
3  3  c  e  yy
4  4  d  r  vv
```

```
second_df:
   C1 C2
1  10  a 
2  20  b 
3  70  g 
4  80  h
```

What I want to achieve is mark rows from first_df, based on values from second_df.
Marking those rows should be based on comparing column values:

```
(first_df['A'] == second_df['C1'] * 10) & (first_df['B'] == second_df['C2'])
```

Expected output should be like this:

```
compared_df:
   A  B  C  D   Match
1  1  a  q  zz  True
2  2  b  w  xx  True
3  3  c  e  yy  False
4  4  d  r  vv  False
```

Could you please point me in a right direction? Which pandas methods should I use to achieve my goal? I've tried many things, but I'm pandas beginner, so it's hard to assess if those attempts were correct.

Comment: I don't understand `first_df['A'] == second_df['C1'] * 10`. Did you mean `/ 10`?

Comment: Or `first_df['A'] * 10 == second_df['C1']` ?

Comment: Ops, sorry, my mistake. Obviously 
```first_df['A'] * 10 == second_df['C1']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create Multiindex on both the dataframes then use **[`MultiIndex.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.isin.html)** to test for the occurrence of the index values of first dataframe in the index of second dataframe in order the create boolean flag:

```
i1 = first_df.set_index([first_df['A'] * 10, 'B']).index
i2 = second_df.set_index(['C1', 'C2']).index

first_df['Match'] = i1.isin(i2)
```

Result

```
print(first_df)

   A  B  C   D  Match
1  1  a  q  zz   True
2  2  b  w  xx   True
3  3  c  e  yy  False
4  4  d  r  vv  False
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is almost completely correct; I think you just multiplied the wrong column by `10`:

```
first_df['Match'] = (first_df['A'] * 10 == second_df['C1']) & (first_df['B'] == second_df['C2'])
```

Output:

```
>>> first_df
   A  B  C   D  Match
1  1  a  q  zz   True
2  2  b  w  xx   True
3  3  c  e  yy  False
4  4  d  r  vv  False
```

Comment: Yes, this multiplication error is my mistake, but actually it wasn't the case. When I'm trying to use that code I'm receiving ```ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects``` and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are the dataframes the same lengths?

Comment: Depends on case, better to assume they're not. Another mistake of mine while writing this post

Comment: Then how should the rows in `second_df` correspond to those in `first_df`?

Comment: thanks for your efforts. Answer posted by Shubham Sharma worked for this case

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing it as sql code and you can import libraries to your project, you might use pandasql library.

```py
import pandasql as psql

compared_df =  psql.sqldf("""
select f.A, f.B, f.C, f.D, 
CASE WHEN s.C1 is not null then 1 else 0 end as Match
FROM first_df f 
LEFT JOIN second_df s ON (f.A *10 = s.C1 AND f.B = s.C2)
""")
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but I can't use pandasql